# How to match background color of an image with background color of Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to Make a class that draws the character at the
center of the screen and match the background color of the image to the background color of the screen, or vice versa. I have already set a value for the background color of Pygame screen to blue, but when I do the same in my `DrawCharacter` class, it just opens the screen with the background color of the image (white). I might just be placing the `bg_color` attribute at the wrong place in my class.

game_character.py

```py
import sys
import pygame

class DrawCharacter():
    bg_color = ((0, 0, 255))
    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Initialize the superman and set starting position"""
        self.screen = screen

        # Load image and get rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/supermen.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Start each new supermen at the center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the superman at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

blue_sky.py

```py
import  sys
import pygame
from game_character import DrawCharacter

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and make screen object
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Blue Sky")
    bg_color = (0, 0, 255)

    # Make superman
    superman = DrawCharacter(screen)

    # Start the main loop for the game
    while True:

        # Check for keyboard and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Redraw screen during each loop pass
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        superman.blitme()
        # make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
    run_game()
```

I expected the background color of the image to be the same as the background color of the Pygame screen, but it is not. The first block of code is for my class file, while the second is for the pygame file

Comment: can't you use PNG image with transparent background and `image.convert_alpha()` to get image without background ?

Comment: you define `bg_color` but you never use `image.set_colorkey()` to make this color transparent in image. See [transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Answer (score 0):

if the image has a transparent background try doing the following in game_Character.py:

```
# Load image and get rect
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/supermen.bmp").convert_alpha()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

If it has a white background you probably want to set the colorkey like so:

```py
    # Load image and get rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/supermen.bmp").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```