# How i can remove the black background on my sprite sheet in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to learn how use sprite sheets on pygame , and on my first try my sprite for some reason have a black background , i don't know how i can fix this problem , i alredy put 000 on the color key but when i do this the sprite be all buggy

```
import pygame


class Spritesheet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, filename, *groups):
    super().__init__(*groups)
    self.filename = filename
    self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

def get_sprite(self, x, y, w, h):
    sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h))
    sprite.set_colorkey(( 0 , 0 , 0))
    sprite.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, w, h))
    return sprite

    pass
```

colorkey 0 0 0

[image]

colorkey with any number

[image]

Comment: @hc_dev new users aren't allowed to inline images

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for the notice, I did'nt know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the color key and remove the line:

<s>`sprite.set_colorkey(( 0 , 0 , 0))`</s>

But use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead of [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert)

<s>`self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()`</s>

```py
self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
```

The pygame documentation notes that:

> The returned Surface will contain the same color format, colorkey and alpha transparency as the file it came from. You will often want to call [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) with no arguments, to create a copy that will draw more quickly on the screen.
> For alpha transparency, like in .png images, use the [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.

So if you call `convert()`, the alpha information per pixel is lost and the image is given an opaque background.

---

When you `blit` the image on a new surface, the target surface must provide a per pixel alpha format. Create a surface with an alpha channel per pixel using the `SRCALPHA` flag:

<s>`sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h))`</s>

```py
sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

---

`Spritesheet` class:

```py
class Spritesheet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, filename, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.filename = filename
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()

    def get_sprite(self, x, y, w, h):
        sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        sprite.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, w, h))
        return sprite
```

Also see:

- [How to convert the background color of image to match the color of Pygame window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976450/how-to-convert-the-background-color-of-image-to-match-the-color-of-pygame-window)
- [Pygame image transparency confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704789/pygame-image-transparency-confusion)

Comment: Nothing change man :/

Comment: @Juw I've extended the answer. My bad. I've overlooked the `sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h))` line.

Comment: oh now work dude , thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

#### What happened?

Assuming your sprite (although you not yet posted the original file `sprite.png`) uses an [Alpha-Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) for transparency, like similar image of [Boyfriend of Friday Night Funkin](https://fridaynightfunkin.fandom.com/wiki/Boyfriend):

[image: Boyfriend image transparent]

You apparently set the *colorkey* to a color which is present in the sprite (black with RGB `0,0,0`).

See the PyGame docs on [`set_colorkey`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey):

> Set the current color key for the Surface. When blitting this Surface onto a destination, any pixels that have the same color as the colorkey will be transparent. The color can be an RGB color or a mapped color integer. If None is passed, the colorkey will be unset.

Thus all the contours (eyes, lips, hears, grid on the microphone, key-laces), which were drawn in black in your sprite, disappeared in new alpha-blended transparency.

You could try any other dominant color of your sprite, like red or white as *colorkey* and see what else disappears. Or you could set the *colorkey* to `None` to unset it.

#### Extending the Sprite class

Maybe you can gain additional advice on extending the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class for your game-objects like explained in Real Python's PyGame tutorial series:

- [Creating Sprites](https://realpython.com/lessons/creating-sprites/)
- [Sprite Images](https://realpython.com/lessons/sprite-images/)

#### Erase background with a special color

And for the **background eraser** to make unimportant parts transparent, this Thread in *Python Forum* recommends the a rare *special color* like `pink`:
[Loading images, transparency, handling spritesheets (part 2)](https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-Loading-images-transparency-handling-spritesheets-part-2)

Comment: hmmm i will try